# How ubiquitous are home water filtration systems in the USA?

Tags: usa, safety, tap-water

I'm planning a trip to the USA from coast to coast in maybe a couple of years and I think I'll stay in App-rented houses (not mentioning a specific one here). I know I can ask each individual renter through the app about that, but in general for the year 2022, how common are home water filtration systems in the USA? Is there any official statistic on it?

Like those that sprout from the side of the kitchen faucet, or even central home filters.

Comment: Do you have a special reason to ask? Do you want to avoid them or do you wonder whether to bring your own?

Comment: If I tell you that 38.9% of all houses have built in water filters, then that is simply an average over all homes across the country .  You will still have to ask each individual home renter whether they actually have an in home filter (because that is *how* statistics work).  That will still even be true of the 67.3% of all app rented homes that have in home water filters.

Comment: This is unanswerable. Domestic water supply in the US is sometimes individual to the property (wells and streams), sometimes municipal, and sometimes water district-supplied. There are thus _tens or hundreds of thousands_ of providers, and a whole lot of them will do it differently than the others.

Comment: Bottled water is ubiquitous in USA (as in most countries).  But I carry a filter when I travel—it's cheaper.  And for what its worth, even in places with good tap water, many homes have refrigerators with built in filtered water dispensers.

Answer (score 2):

It will depend on the state and the gusto of the home owner.

- In some northern states, tap water tastes great and is perfectly healthy without a filter, so there is little chance to find one.
- in Florida, water is ok health-wise, but tastes like cat pee (it is hot, so they add a lot of stuff to restrict bacterial growth). So households where people actually drink water would often have a filter; but if it's a soda-drinker family, they wouldn't bother.
- in some specific places, I wouldn't touch the tap water with a ten-foot pole, filtered or not.
- and so on.

Your best bet is to buy one when you arrive, they are cheap, and you can take it with you.